# Changing the classname of a div with mouseover with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, mouseover

I have a problem with the mouseover event (well, with every event if I use it on a DIV)
My problem is that I want to change the ClassName of a div, by using the mouse over

my html is something like:

```
<head>
<script src="code"></script>
</head>    
<body>  
    <div>Stuff</div>
    <div id="box" class="meme">More stuff</div>
</body>
```

and my javascript is this

```
function change(){
document.getElementById("box").className = "otherName";

}
window.onload= function(){

document.getElementById("box").onmouseover = change;    

};
```

Thank you for your time :)

Comment: You code seems to be working: http://jsfiddle.net/auaLu7f8/

Comment: Try listen event: document.getElementById("box").addEventListener('mouseover', change);

Comment: What is the observed vs. expected behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working. Just add the css class and verify. Let me know if the expectation is something else.

```js
function change(){
document.getElementById("box").className = "otherName";

}
window.onload= function(){

document.getElementById("box").onmouseover = change;    

};
```

```css
.otherName{color:red;}
```

```html
 <div>Stuff</div>
<div id="box" class="meme">More stuff</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your markup is the issue, and not the js code, you have the following line:

```
<script src="code"></script>
```

Which does not make sense, I believe that you are not loading the js code in your page, try as follows:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function change(){
        document.getElementById("box").className = "otherName";
    }
    window.onload= function(){

        document.getElementById("box").onmouseover = change;    

    };
</script>
<style>
    .meme {
        color: red
    }

    .otherName {
        color: blue
    }
</style>
</head>    
<body>  
    <div>Stuff</div>
    <div id="box" class="meme">More stuff</div>
</body>
</html>
```